# How to re-create a Code First Database once it has been deleted?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have **SchoolContext** class that extends DbContext and the **connection string** in Web.Config

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext 
    {   //This class enables CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) functionality 
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    }
```

---

```
<add name="SchoolContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\School.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication-20140718100719;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The database was initially created. I deleted it to check some initializing stuff. But the database is not been created again, it returns an error saying:

*System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot attach the file 'c:\Projects\WebApplication\App_Data\School.mdf' as database 'aspnet-WebApplication-20140718100719'.*

App_data folder is empty (since I deleted the database).
Maybe there are some remaining links/references I need to remove from the projet?

What am I missing?

How can I re-create a Code First Database once it has been deleted?

Thanks

Comment: Check the path `%USERPROFILE%` and delete any SQL related file in the top level of that directory, then try again.

Comment: THanks, I did that and also removed _Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication-20140718100719;_ from the connection string in Web.config

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working by removing *Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebApplication-20140718100719;* from the connection string